# jsf uirepeat tag causinng 100% CPU

Tags: user-interface, repeat

We are using JSF 2.1.7 version, our application is facing high CPU utilzation.
When we check the thread dump it is showing JSF uirepeat components causing the issue.

In code we are using nested uirepeat. Can some one please help.

I am getting the exception below in thread dump:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:446)\`<uirepeat></uirepate>\`
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:405)
```

Comment: Is </uirepate> a typo?

Comment: if you are using nested ui: repeat tag you will get this error.Please user latest version of JSF jars to avoid these kind of errors.